# Trying to add two linked lists in Python, but the resulting Linked List is printing in scientific notation

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm working on SumLists from Cracking the Coding Interview (adding 2 numbers represented by a linked list, where each node contains a single digit - the digits are stored in reverse order)
so for example:  (7-> 1 -> 6) + (5-> 9-> 2) should output (2-> 1 -> 9) because 617 + 295 = 912.

I've written a solution, but for some reason my resulting linked list is printing several numbers in scientific notation - this is a sample of the result :
9.12e-311
9.12e-312
9.12e-313
9.12e-314
9.12e-315
9.12e-316
9.12e-317
9.12e-318
9.12e-319
9.12e-320
9.12e-321
9.14e-322
9e-323
1e-323

This is my code:

```
    def sumLists(self, ll2):
        curr1 = self.head
        curr2 = ll2.head
        sol = LinkedList()
        carry = 0 
        while (curr1!= None) or (curr2!=None) or (carry != 0) : 
            digit = carry 
            if (curr1!=None):
                digit += curr1.data
                curr1 = curr1.next
            if(curr2!=None):
                digit += curr2.data
                curr2 = curr2.next
            sol.insert(digit%10)
            carry = digit/10
        return sol
```

and the supporting functions referenced:

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self,data, next=None, prev=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
        self.prev = prev
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.head = None 
    def insert(self,data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        if(self.head):
            current = self.head
            while(current.next):
                current = current.next 
            current.next = newNode
        else:
            self.head = newNode
```

This is how I'm testing the function:

```
LL1 = LinkedList()
LL2 = LinkedList()
LL1.head = Node(7)
LL1.insert(1)
LL1.insert(6)
LL1.printNode()
LL2.head = Node(5)
LL2.insert(9)
LL2.insert(2)
LL2.printNode()
LL1.sumLists(LL2).printNode()
```

output:

```
7
1
6
5
9
2
2
1.1999999999999993
9.120000000000001
0.9120000000000001
0.09120000000000002
0.009120000000000001
0.0009120000000000002
9.120000000000002e-05
9.120000000000002e-06
9.120000000000002e-07
9.120000000000002e-08
9.120000000000002e-09
9.120000000000002e-10
9.120000000000002e-11
9.120000000000002e-12
9.120000000000002e-13
9.120000000000002e-14
9.120000000000001e-15
9.120000000000002e-16
9.120000000000002e-17
9.120000000000002e-18
9.120000000000002e-19
9.120000000000002e-20
9.120000000000002e-21
9.120000000000002e-22
9.120000000000001e-23
....
9.12e-319
9.12e-320
9.12e-321
9.14e-322
9e-323
1e-323
```

Comment: and what result would you expect for this input `(1-> 0-> 8) + (9-> 9-> 2)` ?

Comment: How did you fill the linked list with data? This is likely not related to the linked list code itself, but rather with what data you put in into the list.

Comment: Welcome to SO. But you need to provide a [mre] including debugging details. For example, where's the definition of ```Node```? And how did you create your lists?

Comment: *"this is a sample of the print statement"*: there is no `print` statement.

Comment: just edited to include the definition of Node, & how I created the lists and my test case.

Comment: -@RomanPerekhrest i would expect (0-> 0-> 1->1)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you used the division operator '/' instead of the '//'. In Python3, unlike Python2, `a / b` will result in a float, even though `a` and `b` are integers.

So, do like this in the `sumList()`.

```
carry = digit // 10
```